# Передача файлов между приложениями в Android. ACTION_SHARE, URI permissions

Tags: android

Ищу способ передачи файлов между приложениями работающий в следующем сценарии:

- У нас в приложении есть список файлов, человек нажимает кнопку Поделиться и мы показываем ему диалог выбора приложений которые могут принять файл. Например он может выбрать Gmail, чтобы создать письмо к которому будет прикреплен выбранный файл или он может передать этот файл по Bluetooth.
- Файл может быть в приватной директории нашего приложения
- Файл может быть вообще в любом месте файловой системы, кроме мест, требующих root привилегии.
- Приложение получающее файл может не иметь `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` разрешения.
- Должно работать начиная с API level 14 и до самых новых версий.

Насколько я понимаю, единственный способ подходящий под все условия это реализация в моем приложении `FileProvider` или собственного `ContentProvider`, который будет выдавать content URI для файла, и это URI мы будем прикреплять к `ACTION_SHARE` Intent с установкой `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`. Есть более простая альтернатива?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге я нашел недокументированную возможность у `FileProvider`, которая позволяет делиться файлами из любого места на устройстве, это элемент `root-path`:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <root-path name="my_root"/>
</paths>
```

При использовании `root-path`, `FileProvider` полностью удовлетворяет все запрошенные мной возможности. Реализация составляет всего десяток строк, `FileProvider` отличный компонент.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [FileProvider.getUriForFile()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#getUriForFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)), чтобы получить URI файла, и [Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION), чтобы передать URI вместе с правами на чтение.

Подробнее [здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file.html#RespondToRequest) и [здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file.html#GrantPermissions).

Никак не могу сообразить, будет ли это работать вообще с любым файлом, к которому есть доступ у исходного приложения. Если все-таки не ко всем, то можно файлы, для которых невозможно передать read permission, копировать в более доступное место.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, вариант с FileProvider я знаю, но FileProvider имеет серьезные ограничения которые не подходят по третьему пункту в моем вопросе, и копировать файлы в более доступное место не хочется. Вероятно я реализую свой ContentProvider, он подходит по всем пунктам, и он будет работать вообще с любым файлом, к которому есть доступ у исходного приложения, но ContentProvider требует много скучного кода и я хотел узнать есть ли более простая альтернатива.